# ODI 12C Smart import with actions using SDK

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

HI I'm able to smart import Projects in ODI using SDK. but i'm unable to use the predefined method which sets actions like merge, create copy, ignore, reuse, while importing the projects.

Please help me to implement the below method,
setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction(java.lang.String pFCOObjType, int pSmartImportAction)

by using below method i'm directly importing projects.
importObjectsFromXml (fnameAndPath, ExportKey, ExportWithoutCipherData);

I want to implement above mentioned actions, please help me. 
thanks

Comment: Gopi,
You should implement first version before approaching for help.
In doing so, once you fulfill the basic requirement of your solution, 
stack-overflow can help pitch-in with anything you missed. 

It is not smart to assume someone will implement all code for merge, create, copy, ignore, reuse (actions) for you, but you can explore more online if you have no idea where to start.

Comment: Nitin I have done my implementation, here is my code,

Comment: https://github.com/Gopi1995krishna/smartImport.git

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not use `setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction` to specify the action for a specific object like a project as in your code :

```
smartImpServ.setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction("Dev_ODI_Project", 1);
```

It can only define the default action for a First Class Object i.e. for all the objects of a specific type. For instance you can set the default actions for any project as CREATE/COPY (equivalent to 1 as you used in your code):

```
smartImpServ.setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction(ISmartImportService.PROJECT_OBJECT_NAME, ISmartImportService.SMART_IMPORT_ACTION_CREATE_COPY);
```

The values you can use as the pFCOObjType parameters are all the Fields ending by `_OBJECT_NAME` in the [ISmartImportService](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/impexp/smartie/ISmartImportService.html) interface.

If you want to specify the action for a specific object, you would need to use a response file from a previous import with the [importFromXml](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/impexp/smartie/ISmartImportService.html#importFromXml-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-char:A-boolean-) method.

Comment: Hi, in ISmartImportService.PROJECT_OBJECT_NAME,  is this is Project name? so can I use Dev_ODI_Project_OBJECT_NAME, where Dev_ODI_Project is name of the project

Comment: No, as I said, you can not specify a single project. The only thing you can specify is the type of object and in this case it's a project. So it will apply the same action for all the projects. ISmartImportService.PROJECT_OBJECT_NAME is a constant defined in the interface, it is already your string. Its value is `"SNP_PROJECT"` as you can see on this page : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/constant-values.html#oracle.odi.impexp.smartie.ISmartImportService.PROJECT_OBJECT_NAME

Comment: I just edited my answer to add an alternative using a response file. That would allow you to specify the action for each object.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but still i'm in confusion. can you please give me an example of only that method or else can you please update my git code with that method, That would be great help to me.

Comment: Which method? setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction or  importFromXml ?

Comment: setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction

Comment: Then the example is already in my post. `smartImpServ.setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction(ISmartImportService.PROJECT_OBJECT_NAME, ISmartImportService.SMART_IMPORT_ACTION_CREATE_COPY);` is what you need to use to use the CREATE/COPY action for all the Projects. You do not need to replace `.PROJECT_OBJECT_NAME` or `SMART_IMPORT_ACTION_CREATE_COPY`, these are Java constants.

Comment: Hi,  i have implemented as you suggested, but it is not creating copy(i have given create copy action) and none of the actions(i tried to do all of them). smartImpServ.importObjectsFromXml (fnameAndPath, ExportKey, ExportWithoutCipherData);
                         smartImpServ.setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction(ISmartImportService.PROJECT_OBJECT_NAME, ISmartImportService.SMART_IMPORT_ACTION_CREATE_COPY);      can you please correct me what's wrong i'm doing.

Comment: You need to use the setMatchedFCODefaultImportAction method before calling importObjectsFromXml.

Comment: Hey, it has been resolved. I have found what's wrong I'm doing. Now everything is working as expected.Thanks for your valuable suggestions, really helpful.